# Modeling an elastic pendulum in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I want to model a simple elastic pendulum in Modelica;
But i did not get a proper result - could anyone help?
Mass, nominal pendulum length and gravitational constant are taken to be one.

```
model SP
  parameter Real k = 1; "spring constant"
  Real y1(start=1), y2(start=0),y3,y4;
  Real ld;

equation 
  ld= k* (sqrt(y1^2+y2^2)-1)/sqrt(y1^2+y2^2);
  der(y1) = y3;
  der(y2) = y4;
  der(y3) = -y1*ld;
  der(y4)= -y2*ld;


end SP;
```

Comment: What result are you getting, and how is it not proper?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you used variable names that explain the intended meaning, or you add comments with an explanation, as you did for "k".

Answer (score 3):

First there is a small syntax error. Move the comma after the `k = 1` to after `"spring constant"`:

```
  parameter Real k = 1 "spring constant";
```

Second, give `y3` and `y4` initial conditions. Either by using `start` or `initial equation`. Here's a plot of the solution for `ld` in Wolfram SystemModeler:

[image: Plot of the variable <code>ld</code> in Wolfram SystemModeler]